# Extract attachments inside a PDF file with VBA

Tags: vba, pdf

I have a PDF file, which consists of an attachment. I want to extract/save this file via VBA.
Being unable to find a solution to that on google I hope to get some help here.

FYI: I have an Adobe Acrobat subscription, therefore the Adobe Type Library is working.

[image]

What I found is a documentation from Adobe and I think this function gets near to what I am searching for, but I am clueless how to use is - to be more specific: I am not sure what parameters to hand over. The second parameter could be String, but how do I specify the first parameter?

Doc: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/apireference/index.html

Function: **PDFileAttachmentSaveToFile**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically extract an xml invoice from a PDF invoice there are many methods from manual press keys to very complex use of Acrobat SDK.

[image]

Or do it the simplest way of all which is to use poppler currently version 23-08 (https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows)

[image]

You can wrap that in  a drag&drop.cmd or RightClick SendTo or batch file shortcut for all files in a folder as its a one line program.

Here is your starter command to build upon, and you can even shell exec that command with parameters from VBA.

`pdfdetach -save 1 -o invoice1-factur-x.xml invoice1.pdf`